# Javascript illegal character error

Tags: javascript, html

The onclick Parameter is not working, why?

```
mydiv.innerHTML = mydiv.innerHTML + '<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D1D1; height: 50px; width: 100%; color: #464646; font-family: RobotoMedium;" onclick="seite5_wechseln('+variable+')">';
```

Hope there is a solution.

Comment: What's the value of `variable`?  Probably the issue is that you want to use it as a string constant, but you left off the quotes.

Comment: its something like: acc2

Comment: a demo on jsfiddle would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are passing a string to `seite5_wechseln` function. But you are not enclosing it with quotation mark.

try:

```
mydiv.innerHTML = mydiv.innerHTML + '<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D1D1; height: 50px; width: 100%; color: #464646; font-family: RobotoMedium;" onclick="seite5_wechseln(\''+variable+'\')">';
```

Comment: While this is correct, there are many things wrong with the OP's code that can and should be addressed, rather than patching the one bit that doesn't work.

Comment: @T.Jansen you're welcome. If that was helpful to you, pleas mark it as `anaswer`

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong with this...

Try this instead. I call it "doing it properly" ;)

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.style.cssText = [
    "border-bottom: 1px solid #D1D1D1",
    "height: 50px",
    "width: 100%",
    "color: #464646",
    "font-family: RobotoMedium"
].join(";");
newdiv.onclick = function() {
    seite5_wechseln(variable);
};
mydiv.appendChild(newdiv);
```

Further improvements can be made, such as defining a CSS class for your element and putting the styles there (use `newdiv.className = "myclass";` to set it to your element), as well as using `addEventListener` rather than the `.onclick` assignment, but this is already a huge improvement over your original code.